# Fixed distance between slides in slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

Help me please. I have an 8-slide infinite scroll slider on my site. By default, 4 slides are displayed on the screen, then using the buttons on the right, you can switch one slide at a time. The distance between slides is always the same 20 pixels. I need the right border of my slider to match the border of my toggle buttons.
[image]
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    prevArrow: ".project__buttons-prev",
    nextArrow: ".project__buttons-next",
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1600,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 980,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          adaptiveHeight: true,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 850,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
      },

      {
        breakpoint: 375,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

```css
.projects {
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100svh;
  max-width: 1560px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projects__title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: var(--medium);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.slider {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1560px;
}

.slider img {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-desc {
  max-width: 365px;
  text-align: left;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slide-desc h3,
p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.slide-desc h3 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.slide-desc p {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

.project__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<section class="projects" id="projects">
  <h2 class="projects__title wow animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Projects</h2>
  <div class="slider wow animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527" alt="projects-picture-one" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Delivery of Automation Equipment</h3>
        <p>Year: 2015</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmenbashi Complex of oil refineries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?" alt="projects-picture-two" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Yoloten Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?0" alt="projects-picture-three" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>EPC project on Construction of Water Purification System</h3>
        <p>Year: 2017</p>
        <p>Customer: Municipality of Ashgabat</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?1" alt="projects-picture-four" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Chaloyuk Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?2" alt="projects-picture-five" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Bagtyyarlyk-2 Fiscal Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?3" alt="projects-picture-six" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of Electrical & Instruments spare parts for offshore</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Petronas Charigali Turkmenistan Sdn. Bhd.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?4" alt="projects-picture-seven" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of required spare parts for overhauling of various pumps</h3>
        <p>Year: 2021</p>
        <p>Customer: Lukoil Uzbekistan</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?5" alt="projects-picture-eight" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, installation and commissioning of custody transfer metering units</h3>
        <p>Year: 2022</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project__buttons wow animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">
    <svg id="button1" class="project__buttons-prev" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M29 34L20 25L29 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="button2" class="project__buttons-next" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M21 34L30 25L21 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried in different ways, in one of them everything is fine at a resolution of 1920 by 1080, but again it does not match on 4K monitors. Please help me solve the problem. Screenshots and code snippets are attached below. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could shift the buttons to the left using `margin-right`. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    prevArrow: ".project__buttons-prev",
    nextArrow: ".project__buttons-next",
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1600,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 980,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          adaptiveHeight: true,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 850,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
      },

      {
        breakpoint: 375,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

```css
.projects {
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100svh;
  max-width: 1560px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projects__title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: var(--medium);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.slider {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1560px;
}

.slider img {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-desc {
  max-width: 365px;
  text-align: left;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slide-desc h3,
p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.slide-desc h3 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.slide-desc p {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

.project__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px 25px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<section class="projects" id="projects">
  <h2 class="projects__title wow animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Projects</h2>
  <div class="slider wow animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527" alt="projects-picture-one" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Delivery of Automation Equipment</h3>
        <p>Year: 2015</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmenbashi Complex of oil refineries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?" alt="projects-picture-two" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Yoloten Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?0" alt="projects-picture-three" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>EPC project on Construction of Water Purification System</h3>
        <p>Year: 2017</p>
        <p>Customer: Municipality of Ashgabat</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?1" alt="projects-picture-four" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Chaloyuk Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?2" alt="projects-picture-five" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Bagtyyarlyk-2 Fiscal Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?3" alt="projects-picture-six" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of Electrical & Instruments spare parts for offshore</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Petronas Charigali Turkmenistan Sdn. Bhd.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?4" alt="projects-picture-seven" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of required spare parts for overhauling of various pumps</h3>
        <p>Year: 2021</p>
        <p>Customer: Lukoil Uzbekistan</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?5" alt="projects-picture-eight" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, installation and commissioning of custody transfer metering units</h3>
        <p>Year: 2022</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project__buttons wow animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">
    <svg id="button1" class="project__buttons-prev" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M29 34L20 25L29 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="button2" class="project__buttons-next" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M21 34L30 25L21 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

Or you could compensate for the right margin and white space between the `<picture>` and slide container of the slides by adding a negative `margin-right`, adding the offset to the `width` and adding the offset to the `max-width` on the `.slider` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slider").slick({
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    prevArrow: ".project__buttons-prev",
    nextArrow: ".project__buttons-next",
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1600,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 980,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 3,
          adaptiveHeight: true,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 850,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 2,
        },
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
        },
      },

      {
        breakpoint: 375,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          adaptiveHeight: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
});
```

```css
.projects {
  height: 100vh;
  height: 100svh;
  max-width: 1560px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.projects__title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: var(--medium);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.slider {
  height: auto;
  width: calc(100% + 30px);
  max-width: 1590px;
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.slider img {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-desc {
  max-width: 365px;
  text-align: left;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.slide-desc h3,
p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.slide-desc h3 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.slide-desc p {
  margin-top: 0.9rem;
}

.project__buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" integrity="sha512-17EgCFERpgZKcm0j0fEq1YCJuyAWdz9KUtv1EjVuaOz8pDnh/0nZxmU6BBXwaaxqoi9PQXnRWqlcDB027hgv9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<section class="projects" id="projects">
  <h2 class="projects__title wow animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">Projects</h2>
  <div class="slider wow animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527" alt="projects-picture-one" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Delivery of Automation Equipment</h3>
        <p>Year: 2015</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmenbashi Complex of oil refineries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?" alt="projects-picture-two" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Yoloten Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?0" alt="projects-picture-three" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>EPC project on Construction of Water Purification System</h3>
        <p>Year: 2017</p>
        <p>Customer: Municipality of Ashgabat</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?1" alt="projects-picture-four" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Chaloyuk Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?2" alt="projects-picture-five" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, Installation and Commissioning of Bagtyyarlyk-2 Fiscal Gas Metering Station</h3>
        <p>Year: 2016</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?3" alt="projects-picture-six" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of Electrical & Instruments spare parts for offshore</h3>
        <p>Year: 2018</p>
        <p>Customer: Petronas Charigali Turkmenistan Sdn. Bhd.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?4" alt="projects-picture-seven" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply of required spare parts for overhauling of various pumps</h3>
        <p>Year: 2021</p>
        <p>Customer: Lukoil Uzbekistan</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <picture>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/365/527?5" alt="projects-picture-eight" width="365" height="527" />
      </picture>
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h3>Supply, installation and commissioning of custody transfer metering units</h3>
        <p>Year: 2022</p>
        <p>Customer: Turkmengas</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="project__buttons wow animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">
    <svg id="button1" class="project__buttons-prev" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M29 34L20 25L29 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
    <svg id="button2" class="project__buttons-next" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="24.5" stroke="black" />
      <path d="M21 34L30 25L21 16" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No both versions didn't help. What else can I do?

Comment: How did both versions not help? They solve the problem you were experiencing with regards to the visual right edges of the slides and the navigation buttons not being at the same x-coordinate of the Cartesian space.

Comment: In my case, they didn’t solve the issue, that is, it seemed to be solved for the 4k version, but usually 1920 by 1080 is not. That is, for the first solution on 4k, it sits well right along the edge, but on full hd, the button is 25 pixels to the right of the edge of the slider.
In the second solution, the situation is slightly different, already the end of the fourth slide goes beyond the edges of the slider in the version on full hd . What can be done with it?

Comment: Have your images be consistent with the space the slider takes up. The `375px` width of them does not suitably match up to the `.slide` widths most of the time, resulting in extra blank space.

Comment: What can you advise to do in this case? I made the image size 352 pixels, as a result, it is normal on a full hd screen, but on 4k the slides do not occupy the entire width of the slide, and it is precisely its right side. This distance of 20 pixels between slides should not be on the fourth slide on the screen, that's it, it prevents the fourth slide from filling the right edge of the slide. How to achieve this?